# Python : How could I execute 100 process simultaneously?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, locking

**What I want to achieve**:

I want to run 100 processes simultaneously because it takes too much times when I execute it as a for loop. For example : With a for loop my function will wait until the first requests is sent to send the second one. But I want the 100 requests to be sent simultaneously.

**Actual results**:

My function doesn't execute the process simultaneously. It execute one process by one.

**Expected results**:

What I've tried : So I tried to run 100 process simultaneously with the multiprocessing module but it didn't go as expected. When I tried to implement the multiprocessing module to my code it has run the same way as the version without multiprocessing by running one process by one.

I might miss something.

Here is the code that I used before.

***Version without multiprocessing*** :

```
import openpyxl
import requests

def getRowCount(file,sheetName):
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)
   return(sheet.max_row)

def readData(file,sheetName,rownum,columno):
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
   return sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=columno).value

path = my_excel_file
sheetname = my_sheetname
rows = getRowCount(path,sheetname)

def funct():
   for i in range(2, 100):
      name = readData(path,sheetname,i,1)
      data = "name":{}.format(name)
      s = requests.Session()
      session = s.post(url,headers=s.headers,data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    funct()
```

Here is the code that I'm trying to use to solve my issue.

***Version with multiprocessing*** :

```
import openpyxl
import requests
from multiprocessing import Process,Lock

def getRowCount(file,sheetName):
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)
   return(sheet.max_row)

def readData(file,sheetName,rownum,columno):
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
   return sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=columno).value

path = my_excel_file
sheetname = my_sheetname
rows = getRowCount(path,sheetname)

def thread.task(lock,i):
    lock.acquire()
    name = readData(path,sheetname,i,1)
    data = "name":{}.format(name)
    s = requests.Session()
    session = s.post(url,headers=s.headers,data=data)
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    processes = [Process(target=thread_task, args=(lock, i)) for i in range(2,100)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

How could I do to execute all my process simultaneously?

If there is a better solution than multiprocessing to achieve what I want please let me know.

**UPDATE**

I can now run my process simultaneously.

***UPDATE Version with multiprocessing*** :

```
import openpyxl
import requests
from multiprocessing import Process,Lock

def getRowCount(file,sheetName):
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)
   return(sheet.max_row)

def readData(file,sheetName,rownum,columno):
   workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
   sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
   return sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=columno).value

path = my_excel_file
sheetname = my_sheetname
rows = getRowCount(path,sheetname)

def thread.task(i):
    name = readData(path,sheetname,i,1)
    data = "name":{}.format(name)
    s = requests.Session()
    session = s.post(url,headers=s.headers,data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = [Process(target=thread_task, args=(i,)) for i in range(2,100)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

I deleted the lock off my code and now it works. It seemed that the lock was blocking other process to run simultaneously.

Comment: What CPU are you using that you can run 100 simultaneous processes?

Comment: You may use coroutines. It's designed to minimize I/O waiting time. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine An example with requests here: https://dev.to/matteo/async-request-with-python-1hpo

Comment: @Chris - since the workload includes a remote `requests` call, its reasonable to have multiple processes per cpu. 100 may be a bit large, but as long as the workload doesn't swamp memory and cause swapping, it'll be fine.

Comment: You defeat multiprocessing when they all wait on a lock for the others to complete. You could gather the information from the spreadsheet in the parent and pass that to the subprocesses.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you! Now it works. I deleted the lock off my args and I only let i as args.

Comment: @Chris was right I cannot run 100 simultaneous processes my cpu can't take it.

Comment: Number of processes depends on how much CPU/memory bound work you will do in each task. Instead of creating your own processes, you could use multiprocessing.Pool and set number of pool processes. If you are cpu intensive, then process of `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1` is good. But since you are doing some waiting for the request, `multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2` would be good too. You could even up that to 3, 4, 5 until it hurts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try going up a layer and do the concurrent requests via parameters fed into your script in a for loop using bash. From what I am reading in your code, there doesn't appear to be any dependency between the processes you want to run in parallel (the requests you are making) so given that it's safe to run these as 100 separate calls to the same python script and let the operating system worry about the concurrency.

You should be able to achieve this by adding parameters in a bash for loop like so:

```
for i in {2..100}
do
    run_script.py $i
done
```

Then in your python script you'd grab this parameter using the sys module

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = sys.argv[1] # 0 is the name of the script being ran (e.g. run_script.py)
    funct(i)
```

then rewrite your funct function to handle the parameter. I hope this helps!

P.S. If you need to do more complicated process coordination the invoke library can help a lot: http://www.pyinvoke.org/

Comment: Thank you I will take a look on the invoke library.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people do not care about learning multiprocessing in Python. They just want to get things done.

Some of them use GNU Parallel to do the multiprocessing for them. This way they just have to make a single threaded program that takes an argument.

In your case you should be able to make this change:

```py
def funct(i):
    name = readData(path,sheetname,i,1)
    data = "name":{}.format(name)
    s = requests.Session()
    session = s.post(url,headers=s.headers,data=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":if __name__ == "__main__":
    funct(sys.argv[1])
```

Then you can run:

```
seq 200 | parallel --jobs 100 python myscript.py {}
```